# How can I start a virtualbox vm remotely on a Windows host?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, remote-control

I've tried KpyM as an SSH server as well as cygwin. Neither vboxmanage nor vboxheadless seem to be able to recognized the virtual machines.

commands run as expected via command prompt on the host, but I'm looking for a remote solution without a gui--so, no remote desktop.

is this possible?

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Can you post an error message or something?

Comment: /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sun/VirtualBox/VBoxHeadless.exe -startvm "ubuntu"


VirtualBox Headless Interface 3.1.2
(C) 2008-2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
All rights reserved.

Invalid machine name!

Comment: Try this: `VBoxManage.exe list vms`

Comment: i get the same message as if i just ran vboxmanage.exe--its the basic help. otherwise, it has either invalid parameter: 'list' or unknown option -list depending on the syntax of "list"